# Native mac scrollbar in emacs?

Tags: osx, themes, scroll-bars, gui

Emacs comes with it's own solution for scrollbars(rather than using native macOS scrollbar) and honestly, I find them kinda intrusive and ugly. Can I somehow configure scrollbars to use native mac scrollbar which only pops up when scrolling. Kinda like this :- [image]

Or is this something that's out of our hands to configure? If it is, is there a hack that can make it work/appear like native mac srollbar?

Comment: I don't think what you seek is possible.  I have configured my Emacs with a minor mode that removes scroll bars when the buffer is less than a full screen or adds scroll bars when more than a full screen.  I understand that's not what you want, but it is the closest thing that I can think of.  Something like that might perhaps be adapted to achieve an affect similar to what you want to achieve, but it would not be as pretty as an all OSX solution.

Comment: Oh well. That's a bummer. Can we at least hope to see to native GUI elements in future major emacs releases?

Comment: Currently, it's not possible. It's listed in the todo list `C-h C-t`, under `NeXTstep port` (along with a number of other issues). All that is needed is someone willing to take on the challenge of implementing it (Emacs is an open source project, after all). I don't think it would be *that* hard, but it would require some rewiring of the NS layout system. The only problem I see is systems without a track pad or a magic mouse -- do we need a way to make the scroll bars appear, or will the system handle that for us?

Comment: Do you really need scrollbars? I just always remove them by calling `scroll-bar-mode` (all frames) or `toggle-scroll-bar` (current frame).

Comment: I dont like scrollbars in emacs too. I've them disabled all the time. But, If i could get it to work like other mac apps, I'd love to have it on